# How do I get the correct style.width value inside a webView?

Tags: android, webview, position, android-webview

After looking all around for solutions, I am just tired of trying out every straw I find.

So, my situation is like this:

I have a scrollable `div` with floated images in it and I am using `scrollLeft`, `offsetLeft` and `style.width` to dynamically expand this `div`.

Now, while this is working great on iOS and PC, on Android (7") the `scrollLeft` value is scaled down nearly to 50%! However `style.width` value is not scaled down, like the other ones.

This would be the css for my items:

```
.slider-item {
  margin: 0 13px 0 0;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  height: inherit;
}
```

And my `viewport`:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

My questions:

- is there somewhere a complete guide to webview from the HTML/JS point of view? because most of the time I stumble on solutions, where it is necessary to adjust the android-app - i would like to avoid that.
- how can I determine the adapted scale of my device using JavaScript or the correct style.width respectively the correct image position?

If someone could explain this to me, I would be so happy!

---

PS.: Just found an additional bug: When I have scrolled some elements to the left, so far, that I reached the empty area; then tap in the empty area, it actually opens a link of one of the elements, which is by now out of sight! But the point where I tap would fit to the actual position, where the element should be on a normal display.

I am quite lost with this o_O

---

Edit: I mistakenly had put the wronk variable here: it's the `syle.width` of my slider-items, which is wrong, not their `offsetLeft`.

---

Working with @media might be impossible, as my window.innerWidth is 1280px on android and 1024 on iOS. Both show an `offsetWidth` or `width` property for my slider-items of 300px - BUT Android `scrollLeft` shows 155px, when I already have scrolled away one whole picture, which should have been 300px wide - there's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried playing with WebView initial scale? Like this: `webView.setInitialScale(100);`

Comment: this is not a JS-Function or a valid HTML-Parameter - right? I am somewhat limited in the editing of the android-app, as it is developed by someone else, who is not always available. But I don't think that the webview is in someway scaled - it was designed as a very plain and simple container.

Comment: `setInitialScale` is a Java method on class `WebView`. You need to have access to the application source code in order to call it. In general Android discourages you to specify dimensions in pixels, because the result will look differently on devices depending on their screen resolution. Check out [Android WebView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), section **Building web pages to support different screen densities**. Some of the stuff there might be relevant to your problems.